How to change webview2 fit to page button on PDF toolbar default to fit to width?
I am using a WebView2 control in a WPF application in C# to render a local pdf document.
It is working fine. However, I'd like the "Fit to Page" button default to "Fit to width" when a PDF file is displayed in the WebView2 control.
How can I change the default behavior?
Base on KJ's reply， I did try below code and it works.
webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("file:///c:\temp\sample.pdf#view=FitH")

The MS PDF team said that 2 page view through URL param is not supported. They support a limited set, including fit to height and width, and destination within PDF. WebView2Feedback

If your web viewer is capable / able to accept file directives it is possible to append instructions after the file.pdf name.
These were designed for Acrobat Reader 8 embedded in Internet Explorer. So often do not work with Adobe Acrobat DC PDF viewer in Chromium's like Edge!
However if calling Edge as a web app you should be able to test a call such as
msedge.lnk --app="file:///%cd%\neon1.pdf#view=FitH"
Which will for me produce as a user a Desktop FIT Horizontal Web View. You should be able to adapt similar for any coded calling a PDF.


Thanks for the reply.
I did try to use  webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate("file:///c:\temp\sample.pdf#view=FitH"), and it works.
